# controlling mainBundle resource paths iOS development

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I am trying to set up an ipad app that relies on using javascript for part of its functionality. I need to have the files in a folder named javascript to have some code I am using work properly.

I have created a symlink from my javascript files into the folder I set up and have included the files in the copy bundle resources in the appropriate build phase.

My issue is that under that section xcode says the files are in javascript/...
So in theory everything should be in the right folder. However, in my code I am using

```
[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: pathName ofType:nil]]
```

and it returns nil when I set the path to the file in the file path and name listed in xCode.

Is there something I am not doing right to the app to have to proper file path names?

I am using the ipad simulator and xCode 5

Answer (score 0):

For files that are in a subdirectory of your app bundle, you want to use the method `pathsForResourcesOfType:inDirectory:`

Comment: my issue is not that I cannot access files in a subdirectory, it is that a subdirectory I am trying to create is not being created. So basically my extra folder is not being used in the bundle for the app.

Comment: If you are trying to read the file using the `pathForResource:ofType:` method, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: I am only getting the file location, I have other code that does things with the location that it finds.

Comment: If you want a file that is in a subdirectory of your bundle, you have to name the subdirectory explicitly with `pathsForResourcesOfType:inDirectory:`. You can't put a directory name in the filename in a call to `pathForResource:ofType:`. It won't work.